# Why is $g$ a measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis

I am refering to the last line, $g\in M^+(X,\mathbf{X})$, which means $g$ is a nonnegative measurable function in Bartle's notation.

I can clearly see $g$ is non-negative, but why is $g$ measurable?

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Recall pointwise Limit of sequence of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: Thanks! Why is each $g_k$ measurable?

Comment: Note that each $f_n$ is measurable. $g_k$ is of type $f_n$.

Comment: I see, by default if $f$ is in $L^p$, then $f$ must be measurable right?

Comment: You are right. Recall that the space $L^p$ is the class of measurable functions(actually it is up to equivalence class up to measure zero...) satisfying $\int |f|^p <\infty$.